# Power Integral of Rational function from Edwards book

Tags: integration

I am struggling to prove that the value of

$$
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(x+2)\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
$$

is

$$
\pi(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}})
$$

I have split this into two integrals using partial fractions to get
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{x(1-x)}} - \int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+2)\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
$$

My issue now is to find the value of the integral 
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+\alpha)\sqrt{x(1-x)}}
$$

for $\alpha$ = 1,2.

Can anyone offer some advice on how I may do so ?

Comment: see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under $x\to \sin^2x,\tan x\to x$, one has
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+\alpha)\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\\
&=&2\int\limits_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{dx}{\sin^2x+\alpha}\\
&=&2\int\limits_{0}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\sec^2xdx}{\tan^2x+\alpha\sec^2x}\\
&=&2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+\alpha(1+x^2)}\\
&=&2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+\alpha)x^2+\alpha}\\
&=&\frac{2}{1+\alpha}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}}\\
&=&\frac{2}{1+\alpha}\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}}}\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\alpha(1+\alpha)}}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Such a nice and obvious way ( ...now !) to progress to quoted result. Great stuff and great Wiki-reference .